# Git command issue on Mojave

Tags: git, macos-mojave

Recently I have updated Mojave and on accessing git commands I am getting below error message:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [macOS Mojave: invalid active developer path after updating to Mojave from High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753865/macos-mojave-invalid-active-developer-path-after-updating-to-mojave-from-high-s)

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution for the same, write the below command in terminal, it will install a software and problem will be resolved:

```
xcode-select --install
```